# What is differerent between using $subject and substr($subject,3) in example preg_match() in php.net

Tags: php, regex

I read how to use function preg_match in http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php, I don't know what is differerent between using $subject and substr($subject,3) in preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 3) and preg_match($pattern, substr($subject,3), $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE). Please help me understand and check below function that why does it return empty array?

```
<?php
    $ch=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.1gom.us/ti-le-keo-malaysia.html");
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    $content = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $regex = '/<div class="tabbox" id="tabbox">(.*)<\/div>/';
    preg_match($regex, $content, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 3);
    $table = $matches[1];
    print_r($table);
?>
```

Comment: i suggest use an HTML parser for this, `DOMDocument` in particular

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will obtain the same result. But if you use substr, you will create a new string for nothing, when the last parameter of preg_match only ask to begin the search at a particular offset of the subject string.

The reason you obtain an empty result is probably due to the fact that `.` can't match newlines by default. You can change this behavior with the `s` modifier:

```
$regex = '~<div class="tabbox" id="tabbox">(.*?)</div>~s';
```

(Note the use of a different modifier to not have to escape slashes. Note too the use of a non-greedy quantifier to stop at the first occurence of `</div>`)

However, as noticed in comments, extracting informations from an html document is more easy with a combo DOMDocument/DOMXPath (depending of how looks your document and what you are trying to do).

Comment: I try your $regrex but the result is still empty. I tried dom but empty too :( I used require_once 'simple_html_dom.php'; 
 
 $url = "http://www.1gom.us/ti-le-keo-malaysia.html";
 $html = file_get_html($url);
 $content = $html->find('#tabbox');
 echo '<pre>';
 foreach ($content as $e) {
  echo $e->firstChild();
  //break;
 }

Comment: @NamNguyen: There is no element with `id="tabbox"` in your file.

Comment: @NamNguyen: The element you are looking for is probably dynamically build on client side, or is hidden in a frame.

Comment: it's true but why do I see tables on browser?

Comment: Because these tables, even if they are not hardcoded in html, are created with javascript.

Answer (score -1):

$subject search value in the full string values of $subject while  substr($subject,3) search values just a part of the $subject variable/ or values that start from index 3 ..

if  $subject = HELLO WORLD
then substr($subject,3) = LO WORLD

Comment: This is the only difference in the example given. Basically, substr($subject, 3) ignores the first 3 characters of $subject.

Comment: Could you help me check function I gave?

Comment: But why in the first case the result is empty?